# it's vs their (country)

Tags: grammatical-number, personal-pronouns, possessive-determiners

What is correct?

```
Australia constantly improves its roads.

Australia constantly improve their roads.

Australia constantly improves their roads.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Singular - *Australia constantly improves its roads* - unless you are talking about an Australian sports team, when you would say *Australia are losing to England in the cricket/rugby etc*.

Comment: Whose roads would Australia improve besides Australian roads? _Australia constantly improves **the** roads_. And, what about _it's_?

Comment: @JohnLawler I thought *it's* was *it is*, and the possessive was *its*. Do you not have that convention in America?

Comment: Yeah, we do. But the question asks about _it's._

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I just misstyped its, sorry.

Comment: The Australian people constantly improve their roads, and hence Australia constantly improves its roads.

Comment: Don’t forget the possibility that *Australia constantly improves **her** roads.*

Answer (score 0):

In British usage, a collective such as a company, or a team may be construed with singular or plural: there is a slight difference of meaning, with the focus on the collective or the individuals. This is not normally extended to countries, but I don't see why it shouldn't be.

American authorities insist on a singular.

I don't know what is the situation in Australian English, but I would hazard a guess that it follows British usage.

"Correct" has no meaning unless you specify which authorities you choose to follow.

Comment: Australia was just an example. English is not my mother language (I live in Austria), so it's pretty irrelevant what type of english it is.

Answer (score -1):

The correct sentence is: *Australia constantly improves its roads.*

Australia is singular in this sentence because here, the group of unspecified people that make up Australia are acting as one.

If you were to discuss conflict *within*, say, a team of Australians, you would want to say "The Australian team **are** fighting" because although they comprise a single unit, they are acting as individuals.

Comment: That's if you subscribe to notional = logical agreement. I also do, but those who don't can't be labelled _wrong_ This has been discussed here many times.